# Append a character at the beginning of next line matching the pattern throughtout the file

Tags: bash, sed, gnu

Test file:

```bash
cat Test.txt
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:100
a.flac

#EXTINF:20
b.flac
```

---

Expected Result

```bash
cat Test.txt
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:100
#a.flac

#EXTINF:20
#b.flac
```

Experiment 1

```
sed -e '/^#EXTINF/a #'  Test.txt
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:100
#
a.flac

#EXTINF:20
#
b.flac
```

### Suggestions?

My experiment adds a new line after appending `#`, I don't want that new line to be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -e '/^#EXTINF/{n;s/^/#/;}' Test.txt
#EXTM3U

#EXTINF:100
#a.flac

#EXTINF:20
#b.flac
```

where

- `n` prints the pattern space (in this case, the line matching `^#EXTINF`), then reads the **n**ext line of input into pattern space
- `s/^/#/` **s**ubstitutes `#` at the start of the newly-read line

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{print} /^#EXTINF/ && (getline > 0) {print "#" $0}' file
```

Print any line and then test the pattern. If pattern matches, the `getline` call fetches the next line for processing. Also `&& getline` is used in order to test if next line exists and we haven't reached the end of file, to avoid printing again the last line if matching.

---

The same without `getline`:

```
awk 'p{$0 = "#" $0; p=0} /^#EXTINF/{p=1} {print}' file
```

Using a flag (`p`), set it when pattern is found. Flag can be used only for the next line it was set, because of `p=0` inside `p{...}`.